# Tool to see all the project references of project/solution

Tags: c#, .net

I have a solution file with has more than 30 projects in it. Different projects are referencing other projects.

I want to see the references of different projects to other projects in a diagram. (it is difficult to expand the "References" node of each project & check the dependencies)

Is there any tool which can generate this diagram for me?

Atul Sureka

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? the ultimate version has Generate dependency graph.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, Yes I am using VS 201o Ultimate

Comment: For those who don't have VS Ultimate, a nice PowerShell script here: http://blog.dantup.com/2012/05/free-dependency-graph-generation-using-powershell-and-yuml

Comment: Thanks MBen VS 2010 dependency graph solved my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Visual Studio? the ultimate version has Generate dependency graph